# Pushing metric data to Cloudwatch for custom auto scaling

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-auto-scaling

We would like to autoscale based on SQS size.

I was able to follow the below link and add custom autoscaling policy across the auto scaling group.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/ec2-auto-scaling-target-tracking-metric-math.html

```
{
    "CustomizedMetricSpecification": {
        "Metrics": [
            {
                "Label": "Get the queue size (the number of messages waiting to be processed)",
                "Id": "m1",
                "MetricStat": {
                    "Metric": {
                        "MetricName": "ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible",
                        "Namespace": "AWS/SQS",
                        "Dimensions": [
                            {
                                "Name": "QueueName",
                                "Value": "my-queue"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "Stat": "Sum"
                },
                "ReturnData": false
            },
            {
                "Label": "Get the group size (the number of InService instances)",
                "Id": "m2",
                "MetricStat": {
                    "Metric": {
                        "MetricName": "GroupInServiceInstances",
                        "Namespace": "AWS/AutoScaling",
                        "Dimensions": [
                            {
                                "Name": "AutoScalingGroupName",
                                "Value": "my-asg"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "Stat": "Average"
                },
                "ReturnData": false
            },
            {
                "Label": "Calculate the backlog per instance",
                "Id": "e1",
                "Expression": "m1 / m2",
                "ReturnData": true
            }
        ]
    },
    "TargetValue": 100
}
```

After execution of this snippet, I see two alarms one for scale in and another for scale out.

Question: Will the above step also publish metric data to Cloudwatch? Because I don't see metric data populating which means no scaling is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to send any SQS metrics to CloudWatch, [they are sent by SQS by default](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html). You can find the `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` metric in CloudWatch, you just need to send messages to `my-queue` and wait a bit (actually, it can take a couple of minutes).